# Ajax Calls in CakePHP 3.x with help of Helpers

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.2

I found hints in the CakePHP 3.x documentation that Helpers can help to "build AJAX functionality" (like here http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers.html#helpers). But I think there is no further and deeper explanation elsewhere in the docs, how to simplify the usage of AJAX-Calls in CakePHP 3.x.

Does anyone know how Helpers can help me to build AJAX functionality? I would like to extend a Form partially with AJAX-funktionality e.g. to request autosuggest data in an input-formfield.

Are there any concepts beside Helpers to easily implement AJAX-Calls in CakePHP 3.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That half-sentence is a leftover from the 2.x docs, and it should be removed, as with CakePHP 3.x the JS helper, which had support for AJAX stuff, has been removed, so there is no AJAX assistance from any built-in helpers anymore.

With CakePHP 3.x you do your AJAX stuff on your own, so the concept you are looking for is basically the way it's done with any other HTML form.